# Can't connect to site hosted on Ubuntu Server VM

Tags: networking, virtualbox, network-bridge, virtualbox-networking

Yesterday I had my Ubuntu Server VM successfully hosting a website that I could access by typing in the IP of the VM (VirtualBox Bridged adapter) in my client's browser.  Today I can't access it.  I checked `ifconfig` and got this back for eth0:

```
eth0     Link encap: Ethernet HWaddr 08:00:27:1b:66:66
         inet6 addr: fe80::aa00:27ff:fe1b:6666/64 Scope:Link
         UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
         RX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
         collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
         RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:3888 (3.8 KB)
```

There is not inet (IPv4) address being shown for eth0.  Why did this disappear and how can I get it back?  Yesterday it was 192.168.0.128

EDIT: `ping www.google.com` returns `ping: unknown host www.google.com`

Comment: Yes, this means that the VM did not receive an IP. What's weird is that it received one yesterday. What you can do is try to reset the interface by `ifdown eth0` then `ifup eth0`, and check if it receives an IP. If it doesn't, what is the output of `cat /etc/network/interfaces`?

Answer (score 0):

On the VM run:

```
sudo dhclient
```

That should make it run out and grab a fresh IP from the router.

I can't say *why* this has happened. Never had it happen to me.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  If nothing else works I will try doing this, but I would rather have my static IP set otherwise I will have to reconfigure my host's hosts files every time the machine reboots.

Comment: I just tried this and it didn't work.  My VM stalled for about 10 minutes.  I tried to run the shutdown now command but it said it could not shutdown, shutdown, reboot, etc. commands did not work after this so I was forced to 'reset' the system.  

I no longer have eth0 show up at all.  I think I need a new VM...

Comment: @CR47 I see.. I'd move back to an auto/dhcp configuration and poke the router or dhcp server (depending on your network) for a static IP. It'll be a lot more robust.

Comment: I reverted back to dhcp which didn't solve the issue.  Tried pinging a few different places, only 127.0.0.1 worked.